# Linq OrderBy Then with Duplicate item

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, sql-order-by

Can I use OrderBy().Then() in linq, on a string property of the entity with Duplicate Value.
for Example

```
public class Test
{
     public Guid Id{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

I want to order this list of the Test entity Based on Name(that can be Duplicate), and then, order the result with Date.

for example

```
public class Test
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class TestLinq
{
    private IList<Test> list;

    public TestLinq()
    {
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        list = new List<Test>
        {
            new Test {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Masoud", Date = dateTime},
            new Test {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Bahrami", Date = dateTime},
            new Test {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Ali", Date = DateTime.Now},
            new Test {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "hasan", Date = DateTime.Now},
            new Test {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Masoud", Date = DateTime.Now},
            new Test {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Bahrami", Date = DateTime.Now},
        };
    }

    public List<Test> Get(string name)
    {
        return list.OrderBy(test => test.Name).ThenBy(test => test.Date).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @ Rahul Singh, when run query i occurred this error "a column has been specified more than once in the order by list. order by must be unique"

Comment: @MasoudBahrami Can you post the whole query, I doubt you specified the Name column twice in order by clause?

Comment: The query you posted looks good.

Comment: @ Shilpa Soni yes, whole query was posted above

Comment: try something like list.OrderBy(test => test.Name).ThenBy(test => test.Date).ToList();

Comment: I dont see any problem with your query. I can give it a try on my machine as well with duplicate names and your class and it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Probably I can get it right, but why you have this string name parameter? You are not using it. Or you want to get all records with this name and then sort them by name and date? 
If you want this then I think the code will work for you:

```
list.Where(t=> t.Name == name).OrderBy(t => t.Name).ThenBy(t => t.Date).ToList();
```

The other problem is that you set DateTime.Now everywhere and ThenBy criteria is not working in this case.

Correct me if I am wrong somewhere. I will be glad to help

Comment: thanks a lot. Yeah name is for filter, and in some situation both Name and Date are Equal values.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't Hesitate, Use this method.

```
    list.OrderBy(test => test.Name).ThenBy(test => test.Date).ThenBy(test => test.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot, Okay, I well test it, But i don't certain, Your solution can be solved It.